# Microsoft Azure - sending emails with attachments

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to send email with attachment (zip file).
I managed to do so, but now my main problem is that I need code to get access_token, if I try GET request to get the code

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Mail.send&state=111111
```

I get error saying that I need to sign up, that's a problem because I can't do so from my app.

I tried this method I found

```
{
   client_id: clientId,
   scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
   grant_type: 'client_credentials',
   client_secret: clientSecret,
}
```

and I get access token but I cannot send a mail with video with that access token as I get http 401, my app has these permissions `Mail.ReadWrite`, `Mail.Send`, `User.Read`

Comment: Could you confirm that you have application permissions Mail.Send, Mail.ReadWrite for the second case when you authenticate with client secret?

Comment: yes I have all permissions with second case it's same azure application, I'm not sure if I need to add some more other permissions?

Comment: Maybe the access to specific user's mailbox is limited due to some policy, but it should be possible to enable it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @Mario Could you decode the token you got from client credentials flow in [jwt.s](https://jwt.ms) website and check what value it has in `roles` claim?

Comment: @Sridevi I tried to decode 2 tokens first one I get when I use code, and second one when there is no code as described in question, there is no roles inside

Comment: While using **Delegated** permissions, you will get them in `scp` claim of decoded token. When you grant permissions of **Application type** and generate token using client credentials flow, then you will get permissions in `roles` claim.

Comment: Yea I'm using Delegated permissions and I get "Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send profile openid email" in scp, will try Application type, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, you need to grant permissions of **Application** type while generating access token using client credentials flow.

I registered one Entra ID application and granted **`Mail.Send`** permission of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check **`roles`** claim for permissions:

[image]

Using this access token, you can send the mail with attachments successfully like this:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userId/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "user@mail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "attachment.txt",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[user: sendMail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)